# CSV Helper Convert String into DateTime

Tags: csvhelper

Need a way to Convert a string in the format "yyyyMMDD" in the csv file into DateTime format "MM/DD/YYYY" using CsvHelper nuget package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Updated for version 20.0+

Setting the `TypeConverterOption` for individual `DateTime` properties.

```cs
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Id,Name,Date");
            writer.WriteLine("1,one,20200623");
            writer.WriteLine("2,two,20190622");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<TestMap>();
            var records = csv.GetRecords<Test>().ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public sealed class TestMap : ClassMap<Test>
{
    public TestMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id);
        Map(m => m.Name);
        Map(m => m.Date).TypeConverterOption.Format("yyyyMMdd");
    }
}
```

Setting the `TypeConverterOptions` for all `DateTime` properties.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("Id,Name,Date");
        writer.WriteLine("1,one,20200623");
        writer.WriteLine("2,two,20190622");
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        var options = new TypeConverterOptions { Formats = new[] { "yyyyMMdd" } };
        csv.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<DateTime>(options);

        var records = csv.GetRecords<Test>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: The Second option solved the problem, i was using  "yyyy/MM/dd" in the formats and was seeing that issue. Thanks David for your help.

Comment: Thanks, from V20.0.0 onwards TypeConverterOptionsCache was moved to the Context. Therefore on your second example you would write:                                 csv.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<DateTime>(options);