# CSV File Parsing

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

since this is the first discussion topic, forgive me in advance if I'm wrong.
My question will be, I have an example of a CSV file in the form of '.txt' and I am using this file.

- Name
- Address
- Direction
- Status
- Duration
- Date

I want to get values like . I used CSVHelper, either I couldn't do it or the formats I wanted were not in that package.
Thanks in advance to those who will help. Attached is the file I want to parse;

```
Name,Address,Direction,Status,Duration,Date
Berat Bey Dörtsan,"05315554622",Outgoing,Unanswered,00:00,00:00,8/4/2022 (9:25:48 AM)
Berat Bey Dörtsan,"05315554622",Outgoing,Answered,00:47,00:47,8/4/2022 (9:27:55 AM)
Berat Bey Dörtsan,"05315554622",Incoming,Answered,00:54,00:54,8/4/2022 (9:35:02 AM)
Berat Bey Dörtsan,"05315554622",Outgoing,Answered,00:19,00:19,8/4/2022 (2:58:43 PM)
Berat Bey Dörtsan,"05315554622",Outgoing,Answered,00:49,00:49,8/5/2022 (9:21:52 AM)
Berat Bey Dörtsan,"05315554622",Incoming,Answered,01:56,01:56,8/16/2022 (10:17:55 AM)
Berat Bey Dörtsan,"05315554622",Outgoing,Answered,00:47,00:47,9/7/2022 (11:02:33 AM)
Berat Bey Dörtsan,"05315554622",Outgoing,Answered,01:19,01:19,9/7/2022 (11:04:35 AM)
Berat Bey Dörtsan,"05315554622",Outgoing,Answered,01:57,01:57,9/7/2022 (11:07:20 AM)
Berat Bey Dörtsan,"05315554622",Outgoing,Answered,04:59,04:59,9/7/2022 (11:12:54 AM)
Berat Bey Dörtsan,"05315554622",Outgoing,Answered,01:50,01:50,9/7/2022 (11:18:36 AM)
Berat Bey Dörtsan,"05315554622",Incoming,Answered,00:37,00:37,9/7/2022 (11:36:36 AM)
Berat Bey Dörtsan,"05315554622",Outgoing,Answered,00:59,00:59,9/7/2022 (11:55:19 AM)
Berat Bey Dörtsan,"05315554622",Incoming,Missed,00:00,00:00,9/7/2022 (12:15:26 PM)
Berat Bey Dörtsan,"05315554622",Outgoing,Unanswered,00:00,00:00,9/7/2022 (12:21:12 PM)
Berat Bey Dörtsan,"05315554622",Outgoing,Unanswered,00:00,00:00,9/7/2022 (12:21:24 PM)
Berat Bey Dörtsan,"05315554622",Outgoing,Answered,00:18,00:18,9/7/2022 (12:36:08 PM)
```

i tried to do it this way;

- Name = Berat Bey Dörtsan
- Address = 05315554466
- Direction = Outgoing
- Status = Unanswered
- Duration = 00:54 - 01:56
- Date = 8/4/2022 (9:25:48 AM)

and i was used these codes;

```
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TextVeriCekme
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        String csvPath = "";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                Title = "CSV Dosyası Aç",
                Filter = "csv files (*.csv)|*.csv",
                CheckFileExists = true,
                CheckPathExists = true
            };

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ofd.FileName);
                csvPath = ofd.FileName;
            }
        }

        public class Foo
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public string Address { get; set; }

            public string Direction { get; set; }

            public string Status { get; set; }

            public string Duration { get; set; }

            [Name("Date")]
            [Format("dd-MM-yyyy")]
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        }

        int sayac = 0;

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IEnumerable<Foo> records = null;
            List<Foo> list = null;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(csvPath))
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();
                list = records.ToList();
                MessageBox.Show("Toplam Kayıt : " + records.Count().ToString());
                foreach (Foo record in list)
                {
                    if (sayac == 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(record.Name);
                        MessageBox.Show(record.Address);
                        MessageBox.Show(record.Direction);
                        MessageBox.Show(record.Status);
                        MessageBox.Show(record.Duration);
                        MessageBox.Show(record.Date.ToString());
                    }
                    sayac++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this way I can't get 'Date' variable. what i want to do in general is a windows form to keep these call logs (date and time).

Comment: `values like`...like what? You didn't finish the sentence. `I couldn't`...what does that actually mean in reality? What did you try, and what went wrong? We don't really know where you're stuck.

Comment: P.S. As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of code, data or error messages. This information is text-based. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please [edit] your question to include code and data as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you.Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far, add some code so it's clear where the issue is.

Comment: FYI, That format is in fact supported by CSVHelper, though you might have to help it with the timedate parsing

Comment: `Format("dd-MM-yyyy")` clearly doesn't match the date/time format in your file

Comment: Are you able to control the format in which the dates are stored in the text file? It would be far better to store them in an unambiguous and automatically-parseable format such as ISO8601

Comment: @ADyson Unfortunately I can't change it, but if you have any other suggestions for how I can extract data from a phone call, that would be great.

Comment: It's nothing to do with them being records of phone calls, particularly. Your specific issue is about parsing the date, as far as I can see...is that correct? Did you try a custom type converter as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/66174585/5947043 or https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/type-conversion/type-converter-options/ or https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/type-conversion/type-converter-options/ ? It's unclear what, if any, research you've done into this already.

Comment: "Duration" seems two be in fact two columns in your CSV, e.g: 00:00,00:00, so you will need two properties in the class.

Answer (score 1):

The format decoration for the date in the `Foo` type is wrong. The date values look like this:

```
M/d/yyyy (h:mm:ss tt)
```

So you need to decorate the type accordingly:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }

    [Name("Date")]
    [Format("M/d/yyyy (h:mm:ss tt)")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

If you are not able to change the attribute, you will instead need to provide a ClassMap configuration as demonstrated here:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/62536666/3043

Comment: Unfortunately this method did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that `Duration` is two columns in your data, since it is not enclosed in double quotes.

> `00:47,00:47` instead of `"00:47,00:47"`.

As such, you can't go by the header names and instead are going to need to use a `ClassMap` to map properties by `Index`.

```cs
void Main()
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\CsvFileParsing.txt"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();
        
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
    }
}

public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Name).Index(0);
        Map(x => x.Address).Index(1);
        Map(x => x.Direction).Index(2);
        Map(x => x.Status).Index(3);
        Map(x => x.Duration).Convert(args => args.Row.GetField(4) + " - " + args.Row.GetField(5));
        Map(x => x.Date).Index(6).TypeConverterOption.Format("M/d/yyyy (h:mm:ss tt)");
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```